# Zalenium on kubernetes with 20-30 testcases in Parallel with multiple dynamic machies

Tags: kubernetes, zalenium, parallel-execution

I have around 4000 testcases to be executed.  I have kubernetes  setup for Jenkins, where dynamic machine is created for each job. I have around 50+ jobs and each job has around 2000 to 3000 testcases.

How should be setup of zalenium on it. As of now using testng i am able to do parallel execution with 10 threads. Can I triggered execution in multiple machines of same job using Zalenium? If yes , can you help me how to do it? Can I run 20-25 testcases in parallel using zalenium where i have around 2500+ testcases.  What should be system configuration and approach?

Thank you,
Trupti

Answer (score 0):

In jenkins build script create a namespace with jenkinss job name and build number ex:
kubectl create ns jobname-buildnumber
deploy zalenium in the specific namespace and run tests
In post script
delete kubernates namespace which was created.
ex: kubectl delete ns jobname-buildnumber
make sure jenkins job name does not have _ as kubernates doesnot allow _ in namespace.